# Reversing an integer in c++

Tags: c++, reversing

Is there any better way to reverse an integer than this?

```
    int reverse(int x) {
        int out=0;
        while(x)
        {
            if(out > INT_MAX/10 || out < INT_MIN/10){return 0;}
            else{
                out = out*10 + x%10;
                x /= 10;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Comment: Please note that C and C++ are different languages. Do not tag both as the best solution may be different for the two.

Comment: Define reverse an integer.  Reverse the string representation of an integer?  Because numbers don't have an obvious reverse function.  Honestly I'd probably convert it to a string, reverse that, then convert it back to an int, unless you really needed performance out of it.

Comment: The way you check for `out` overflow is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any **better way** to reverse an integer than this?

Well, in programming something like **"better way"** isn't well defined. In other words it can mean a number of things. It can be better performance, better memory usage, etc.

However, the most important thing is that the code is **bug free**.

Your code isn't bug free in all cases.

Consider an obscure system where INT_MAX is 41 and then call your function with the value 34.

It will fail.

The problem is that your overflow check ignores the `x%10` part which is added **after** the multiplication by 10. In other words - INT_MAX could have a value where `out*10` won't overflow but once you add `x%10` it will overflow.

Comment: It will also fail with a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in case of C++ there is a very simple way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int Reverse(int x)
{
    // Read number to a string stream
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << x;

    // Take the string in stringstream
    std::string s = ss.str();
    std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
    ss.str(s);

    // Take the number from reversed string.
    int ret;
    if (!(ss >> ret)) ret = 0;

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << Reverse(1234); // Or any number for test.
    return 0;
}
```

This is better in terms of simplicity and understandability of code. It terms of performance, I guess your original implementation could be better.

Comment: Rather than just writing the code explain what is going on in the code.

Comment: You need to add special handling for negative input values. The current code will fail. BTW: `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: @4386427 It worked without including <algorithm> on my VS 2019 so I missed it. Thanks for reminding. Also added overflow check.

Comment: Why not just `if (!(ss >> ret)) ret = 0;`?

Comment: @Evg Thanks for further simplification.